# android studio's emulator not launching flutter app (error)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, build.gradle

[image]

**When i try to run the flutter application via an emulator , the following error pops up. I have recently installed android studio and done the necessary arrangements like setting the path variable to JAVA_HOME.**

**Any help would be highly appreciated, Thank You!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. update android/build.gradle
2. replaced:

> dependencies {
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

with

> dependencies {
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'